# HAProxy Lua how to change server port?

Tags: lua, haproxy

`Server.set_addr (sv, addr)`

I can not understand what the method takes as input.
It would seem that `Server.get_addr(sv)` returns `ip:port` - so you also need to pass `ip:port`, but no. This does not work.

The documentation reads:
`See the documentation for the control socket for more information on the string format.`

Well, I saw that you need to transfer the `ip port: port` (example: `127.0.0.1 port 80`). But that doesn't work either.

The only thing that works is pass only ip (example: `127.0.0.1`).

The question is how to change the port?

Code sample: (if not work - no have any entry in log)

```lua
-- work
-- log entry: changed its IP from 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2 by Lua script.
local newAdr = backendServer.ip
server:set_addr(newAdr)

-- not work
local newAdr = backendServer.port
server:set_addr(newAdr)

-- not work
local newAdr = backendServer.ip .. ":" .. backendServer.port
server:set_addr(newAdr)

-- not work
local newAdr = backendServer.ip .. " " .. backendServer.port
server:set_addr(newAdr)

-- not work
local newAdr = backendServer.ip .. " port " .. backendServer.port
server:set_addr(newAdr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** As of HAProxy 2.2dev7, this functionality has now been merged: `set_addr` takes an additional optional parameter to specify a new port.

---

It's not currently possible to do that via Lua. A look through HAProxy's source code reveals that [`set_addr`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/6318d33ce62580d6ba6d418890e69300715291c4/src/hlua_fcn.c#L1718) calls [`hlua_server_set_addr`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/6318d33ce62580d6ba6d418890e69300715291c4/src/hlua_fcn.c#L1033-L1050), which calls [`server_parse_addr_change_request`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/6318d33ce62580d6ba6d418890e69300715291c4/src/server.c#L1360-L1384), which calls [`update_server_addr`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/6318d33ce62580d6ba6d418890e69300715291c4/src/server.c#L3440-L3507), which only updates the address and not the port. Contrast this with the management socket's [`set server`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/6318d33ce62580d6ba6d418890e69300715291c4/src/server.c#L4610), which calls [`cli_parse_set_server`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/6318d33ce62580d6ba6d418890e69300715291c4/src/server.c#L4248-L4381), which calls [`update_server_addr_port`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/6318d33ce62580d6ba6d418890e69300715291c4/src/server.c#L3509-L3682), which does update the port too.

However, there are two pieces of good news:

1. Since the management socket can do it, you can use it as a workaround.
2. It would be very simple to modify HAProxy's Lua interface to support updating the port, since all the logic is already there. I sent [a patch that does so](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg37196.html) to their mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not necessarily for me, just without this you will have to reserve a port for the servers.

About patch - I have very small knowledge in haproxy for creating him :)

Comment: @KopeMorta I'm planning to write a patch myself if the HAProxy developers approve. I'll comment back here if it ever lands.

Comment: @KopeMorta It got merged!

Comment: That amazing! :)
Now can I use this by manual compilation sources ?

Comment: @KopeMorta Yes, just apply [the patch](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/commit/49bbf528e47793c716ddaba1cb0bdb039f659075.patch) to whatever version you're running and compile.